# Do self-storage owners have a duty to auction liens?

Tags: florida

Florida lien enforcement for self storage operators are governed by [83.306 (link)](http://www.leg.state.fl.us/Statutes/index.cfm?App_mode=Display_Statute&Search_String=&URL=0000-0099/0083/Sections/0083.806.html).

There is a clause indicating:

5) Any sale or other disposition of the personal property shall conform to the terms of the notification as provided for in this section and shall be conducted in a [commercially reasonable (link)](http://www.leg.state.fl.us/Statutes/index.cfm?App_mode=Display_Statute&Search_String=&URL=0600-0699/0679/Sections/0679.610.html) manner, as that term is used in s. [679.610.](http://www.leg.state.fl.us/Statutes/index.cfm?App_mode=Display_Statute&Search_String=&URL=0600-0699/0679/Sections/0679.610.html)

If a customer does not pay, 83.306 provides requirements regarding notices and timeframes for lien execution.

## Questions:

Assume that the customer has not paid and a lien has been delivered  per section (2) has been delivered to the customer for the following questions.

1. Does the storage operator have a duty to auction off the storage unit?
2. If there is no duty to auction, and the storage operator chooses to throw away the items, is the operator obligated to provide notice in a newspaper as per section (4)?

I am unable to find any indication a duty to auction, because it would seem paragraph (4) provides a clause of "other disposition".  IANAL so I hope that if this review is incorrect, someone will point this out.

3. Does "other disposition" include the operator simply throwing away the items?
   Seizing the items?

Or is throwing away the storage contents precluded?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, "other disposition" would include simply throwing the items away.  But that disposal would have to be commercially reasonable.

If you opened up a storage locker and saw that someone was just using it to store tons of newspapers, it would undoubtedly be commercially reasonable to just discard the contents.  The potential value of a couple hundred pounds of recyclable paper isn't worth the expense of bundling it all up and taking it to the recycling center.  If you opened up a storage locker and saw that someone was just using it to store hundreds of pounds of gold bars, it would undoubtedly be commercially unreasonable to just discard the contents because the gold has obvious value.

Comment: Why do you so desperately want to keep editing my questions, Justin? Does it bother you that you can't control something?